# slideDown function needs two click to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidedown, slideup

I'm having a slideDown function on my site. But somehow it doesn't work the first time when you click it. So I need to click two times to make the function work. What can possible be wrong?

I also want the div to slide up when I click on the button again, don't know how I will do this. I tried using slideToggle but it just ended up with the div going up and down a couple of times before closing. Even for this I needed to click two times.

Here is my JS:

```
    function showCart() {
    $("#rollDown").click(function() {
        $("#shopping_cart_page").slideDown();
    });

    /* not relevant for this */
    emptyBag = document.getElementById("emptyBag");
    emptyBag.addEventListener("click", emptyCart);

}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#giveaways">Giveaways</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html#contact_field">Contact </a></li>
                    <li><a id="rollDown">Shopping Bag</a></li>

                </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the function showCart(); trigged to begin with?

Comment: Ah, that must be it. The first time I click it, I call the function, and the second time I click it slide down.

Comment: There you go :) see the example that I posted as an answer. If the elements exists in the DOM tree, you don't really need to put simple click events into a custom function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // Just adding the click event inside the document ready method should do the trick for you.
   $("#rollDown").click(function() {
      $("#shopping_cart_page").slideToggle();
      });
   });
```

HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="rollDown" value="Toggle"/>
<div id="shopping_cart_page">Hi</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/64gn1unk/

Comment: It works fine, as long as I only got one item in my "shopping bag". When I got more than one, it slides up and down on one click.

Comment: Add a fiddle please and we'll have a look? :)

Comment: Oh and yeah, remember that id's should be (read, _must be_) unique. You should have only **one** element with the id `rollDown`.

Comment: I structure my code better, removed unnecessary functions and that made it work. I did like you showed and put the `slideToggle` function on `$(document).ready(function(){` instead of an other function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as the correct one so that others with a similar problem can benefit from it in future. Cheers!